# How to change inserted values to uppercase using MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jakarta-ee

For example I have a web page that inserts values in my MYsql database...then I have this kind of query in my java code

```
insert into orgdetails values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I tried to put `UPPER` before the opening bracket but it doesnt work...what is the correct syntax for this one?

Answer (score 6):

since you are parameterizing the value, why not do it in the application level?

```
xxx.setString(1, val.toUpperCase());
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `emsItem`? and why are you changing the case for a `LONG` data type they are number not strings?

Answer (score 2):

try like that

```
   values (upper(?), upper(?), upper(?), upper(?))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `UCASE()`

Try like:

```
insert into orgdetails values (1, UCASE('asdf'))
```